# Answer copied and filled up with spam

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, plagiarism

The content of one of my [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1576874/201818) was copied and a new [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576879/201818) was created (with some spam added). This was then "corrected" by a user with a score over 2000. Since he was only shown the "new" answer this was not visible to him.

Now I wonder, how can I make sure to avoid this kind of mistake when I review answers? In my opinion, this should have been caught by some kind of automated review. Is there one?

Or maybe it would be a good idea to make a feature request that when you review posts, you can see the other posts to the question as well (including the question itself).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1576879/timeline) of the answer suggests that this didn't happen in the review queue. Apart from that, it's pretty obvious that this is spam, so it [shouldn't have been edited out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/295232), even if the answer weren't copied.

It's good that you worry about this happening to you in the review queue. While showing other answers there may sometimes help, often spammers copy answers from elsewhere on the site (or the Internet) and those cases won't be detected. Also, a First Post / Late Answer to a question with a lot of answers quickly becomes annoying to scroll through if all answers are shown. (The question itself is already shown when you're reviewing an answer.)

In cases like this, i.e. posts with a promotional link, it's good to put some of the content of the post in a search engine to check if it's plagiarized. If you're certain it's not, that would be a moment to edit out the link and leave a comment about [signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232) and [self-promotion](/help/promotion).

> In my opinion, this should have been caught by some kind of automated review. Is there one?

Most posts like these are detected by Smoke Detector, one of the tools developed by [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/), a volunteer organization for combating spam across the Stack Exchange network. (Disclaimer: I'm a member.) This one was not, because the spam is rather obfuscated: even for a human it's hard to read, let alone for a computer.

Comment: Thx, I'll try to keep an eye open for those cases. I wonder though if it wasn't through the review queue the edit (cutting out the spam and leaving the duplicate answer) doesn't make much sense...  I'm curious what lead to it...

Comment: @Albin, `I'm curious what lead to it...`, possibly the ["Active" Tab](https://meta.superuser.com/); either way it was poorly reviewed (in or out of the queue), and using "**Rollback**" (rather than editing) *punishes* the Reviewer.